# Define a type that behaves as stacked arrays

Tags: julia

I have a type that is composed of multiple arrays

```
type VectorWrapper{T}
   x::Vector{T}
   y::Vector{T}
end
```

I want vector functions (let's say `sumabs2`, `norm`, `scale!`, `copy!`, `fill!`, `axpy!`, `map!`, `reduce`) to act on this type as if it was a stacked vector. For instance, I want the following:

```
sumabs2(a) <-> sumabs2(a.x) + sumabs2(a.y)
copy!(a1, a2) <->  copy!(a1.x, a2.x) ; copy !(a1.y, a2.y)
```

I see two solutions:

1. I can define each function one by one, but this is repetitive.
2. I can also define a `size` and `getindex` function

   ```
   type VectorWrapper{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
      x::Vector{T}
      y::Vector{T}
   end
   Base.getindex(a::VectorWrapper, i::Integer) = i <= length(a.x) ? a.x[i] : a.y[i-length(a.x)]
   Base.size(a::VectorWrapper) = map(+, size(a.x), size(a.y))
   ```

   But this is not as performant:

   ```
   a = VectorWrapper(rand(10_000_000), rand(10_000_000))
   @time sumabs2(a)
   # 0.091090 seconds (7 allocations: 208 bytes)
   @time sumabs2(a.x) + sumabs2(a.y)
   # 0.010433 seconds (7 allocations: 208 bytes)
   ```

   I guess `sumabs2(a)` is slower than `sumabs2(a.x) + sumabs2(a.y)` due to the added operation in `getindex`, bound checking, and the lack of SIMD vectorization.

Is there a solution that combines the performance of 1 with the conciseness of 2?

Answer (score 2):

`map` can be a performance trap currently, have you tried writing the `size` method without it?

Also, have you seen https://github.com/tanmaykm/ChainedVectors.jl? It seems like it already might be doing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a stacked array `v` as the main component and making `x` and `y` as its array views...? For example:

```
type VecWrap{T} <: AbstractVector{T}
    v::Vector{T}
    x::Vector{T}
    y::Vector{T}

    function VecWrap{T}( x_in::Vector{T}, y_in::Vector{T} )
        ( nx, ny ) = ( length( x_in ), length( y_in ) )
        v = Vector{T}( nx + ny )
        v[ 1      : nx      ] = x_in
        v[ (nx+1) : (nx+ny) ] = y_in

        x = pointer_to_array( pointer( v ),       (nx,) )
        y = pointer_to_array( pointer( v, nx+1 ), (ny,) )
        return new( v, x, y )
    end
end

Base.getindex( a::VecWrap, i::Int ) = a.v[ i ]
Base.setindex!( a::VecWrap, val, i::Int ) = ( a.v[ i ] = val )
Base.size( a::VecWrap ) = size( a.v )
Base.copy( a::VecWrap ) = VecWrap{Float64}( a.x, a.y )
Base.copy!( b::VecWrap, a::VecWrap ) = copy!( b.v, a.v )

function test()
    n = 10_000_000
    a = VecWrap{Float64}( rand( n ), rand( n ) )
    for loop = 1:3
        println( "loop = $loop" )
        @time sumabs2( a )
        @time sumabs2( a.x ) + sumabs2( a.y )
        @time sumabs2( a.v )
    end
end
```

On my computer, the result is

```
loop = 1
  0.012153 seconds
  0.009812 seconds
  0.009667 seconds
loop = 2
  0.011365 seconds
  0.009657 seconds
  0.009641 seconds
loop = 3
  0.011350 seconds
  0.009658 seconds
  0.009665 seconds
```

and fill!() etc seems to be okay (though not fully confirmed). Defining x and y as SubArray also seems to work with almost the same efficiency (0.009-0.011 sec).